# Not Found The resource requested could not be found on this server

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, cpanel

i can't navigate an open the other page of my website when it depolyed to the server and it display to me an error page with this message :
`404 Not Found The resource requested could not be found on this server!`

I just uploaded my project Symfony application from my pc (localhost) to my server or CPANEL.
i configured the database and i created .htaccess into public_html like so public_html/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
  php_flag display_errors On
  php_value max_execution_time 300
  php_value max_input_time 300
  php_value max_input_vars 1000
  php_value memory_limit 1G
  php_value post_max_size 8M
  php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
  php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php81"
  php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
  php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
```

**My Files inside the Cpanel**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8IID.png)
how Can i Solve it , And Thanks

Comment: What URL are you requesting? Where are your files located? You presumably have another `.htaccess` file in the `/public` subdirectory - please include this in your question also.

Comment: my files located in the public_html , the .htaccess located also there iside the directory pulic_html , and i haven't any second file .htaccess

Comment: What are the URL(s) you are requesting? What is your file structure? Presumably you do have a `/public` subdirectory?

Comment: yes i have the /public directory , i added the screenshot of my files into the cpanel

Comment: And what's inside the `/public` subdirectory and what URL(s) are you requesting?? What URLs are you using to link to your static assets (assuming you have static assets? You should add this information as _text_ to your question, not link to an external screenshot. Were you developing this on Apache locally?